# Is there a good MVVM/MVP/MVC framework for JavaFX?

Tags: model-view-controller, mvvm, frameworks, mvp, javafx

JavaFX with it's binding seems great technology for building UI layer, replacing PHP+AJAX, but are there any frameworks for building database forms applications with JavaFX, or it is meant to write everything from scratch?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should give a try to some recent libraries :

- JRebirth Application Framework to structure your whole application
  http://www.jrebirth.org
- FXForm to manage form
  http://dooapp.github.com/FXForm2/
- DataFX to manage complex tables etc..
  http://www.javafxdata.org

You can find more tools at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/community/3rd-party-1844355.html

Answer (score 1):

Eric Bruno has a nice write up on JavaFX and Database using JavaFX Composer. See his articles at [DrDobbs](http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/javafx-database-programming-with-java-db/224202518)

Comment: I found the article [here](http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/javafx-database-programming-with-java-db/224202518)

Comment: JavaFX Composer is now an obsolete tool.  It is no longer included with NetBeans 7+ and was built to work with the now discontinued and unsupported JavaFX Script langugage.  Instead, use [JavaFX SceneBuilder](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/tools/index.html) which outputs [fxml files](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html) that can be used with recent JavaFX releases.